# NetLogo: "Code can't be run by a patch" Running Program developed in v 4.0.3 in v5.1.0

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to run a NetLogo program developed in version 4.0.3 in NetLogo Version 5.1.0. The program itself runs fine in the older version of NetLogo but when I try to run it in Version 5.1.0, I receive the following error message:

" this code can't be run by a patch, only the observer
error while patch 19 32 running TICK
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'"

I tried making some of the obvious adjustments offered in the transition guide but was unable to debug the program. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Code for the whole program is below:

```
globals [z diver clrrand simp vviolet oorange bbrown yyellow bblue llime total sumdiver matrix-list yellowtrans p
redtrans browntrans violettrans bluetrans orangetrans limetrans]

to setup
  ;; (for this model to work with NetLogo's new plotting features,
  ;; __clear-all-and-reset-ticks should be replaced with clear-all at
  ;; the beginning of your setup procedure and reset-ticks at the end
  ;; of the procedure.)
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
  setup-patches
  set sumdiver 0


  set redtrans       (list 0.0  0.9  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0)   
  set yellowtrans    (list 0.0  0.8  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.0)   
  set browntrans     (list 0.0  0.0  0.8  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.0)   
  set violettrans    (list 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.8  0.1  0.1  0.0)   
  set bluetrans      (list 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.8  0.1  0.1)   
  set orangetrans    (list 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.8  0.2)   
  set limetrans      (list 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0)   

end



to setup-patches
  ask patches [ 
  set z random 100
  if z <= 100 [ set pcolor yellow ]  
        ]
end



to go
  ignite
  fire_spread
  succession
  do_plots
  tick
end




to ignite
  ask patches [if pcolor != black    
      [if random-float 1 < start 
          [set pcolor red]
        ]
      ]
end




to fire_spread

   while [any? patches with [pcolor = red]]  [ask patches [
    if pcolor = red   [set pcolor 14
                      ask neighbors4 [

      if (random-float 1) < p_fire_spread and pcolor != 14 and pcolor != black
        [ set pcolor red]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

end



to succession

  ask patches [


  if pcolor = 14 [
       set clrrand random-float 1
       set p 0
       (foreach redtrans [ 14 yellow brown violet blue orange lime]  [

           if clrrand > p and clrrand <= (p + ?1) [set pcolor ?2  stop]
           set p (p + ?1)
                 ])
        stop                  
      ]





   if pcolor = yellow [
       set clrrand random-float 1
       set p 0
       (foreach yellowtrans [ 14 yellow brown violet blue orange lime]  [

           if clrrand > p and clrrand <= (p + ?1) [set pcolor ?2  stop]
           set p (p + ?1)
                 ])
        stop   

      ]



   if pcolor = brown [
       set clrrand random-float 1
       set p 0
       (foreach browntrans [ 14 yellow brown violet blue orange lime]  [

           if clrrand > p and clrrand <= (p + ?1) [set pcolor ?2  stop]
           set p (p + ?1)
                 ])
        stop                 
      ]



    if pcolor = violet [
       set clrrand random-float 1
       set p 0
       (foreach violettrans [ 14 yellow brown violet blue orange lime]  [

           if clrrand > p and clrrand <= (p + ?1) [set pcolor ?2  stop]
           set p (p + ?1)
                 ])
        stop   

      ]


    if pcolor = blue [
       set clrrand random-float 1
       set p 0
       (foreach bluetrans [ 14 yellow brown violet blue orange lime]  [

           if clrrand > p and clrrand <= (p + ?1) [set pcolor ?2  stop]
           set p (p + ?1)
                 ])
        stop                 
      ]


     if pcolor = orange [
       set clrrand random-float 1
       set p 0
       (foreach orangetrans [ 14 yellow brown violet blue orange lime]  [

           if clrrand > p and clrrand <= (p + ?1) [set pcolor ?2  stop]
           set p (p + ?1)
                 ])
        stop                 
      ]


     if pcolor = lime [
       set clrrand random-float 1
       set p 0
       (foreach limetrans [ 14 yellow brown violet blue orange lime]  [

           if clrrand > p and clrrand <= (p + ?1) [set pcolor ?2  stop]
           set p (p + ?1)
                 ])
        stop                 
      ]

    ]





end



;;  yellow is 45, brown is 35,  violet is 115, sky is 95, green is 55,lime is 65,  



to do_plots


set oorange count patches with [pcolor = orange]
set bbrown count patches with [pcolor = brown]
set vviolet count patches with [pcolor = violet]
set llime count patches with [pcolor = lime]
set yyellow count patches with [pcolor = yellow]
set bblue count patches with [pcolor = blue]
set-current-plot "abundances"
set-current-plot-pen "orange"
plot oorange
set-current-plot-pen "brown"
plot bbrown
set-current-plot-pen "violet"
plot vviolet
set-current-plot-pen "lime"
plot llime
set-current-plot-pen "yellow"
plot yyellow
set-current-plot-pen "blue"
plot bblue




 set total bbrown + oorange + vviolet + llime + yyellow + bblue
   set diver (1 / ((bbrown / total) ^ 2 + (oorange / total) ^ 2 + (vviolet / total) ^ 2 + (llime / total) ^ 2 + (yyellow / total) ^ 2 + (bblue / total) ^ 2))
   set-current-plot "Simpson's diversity index"
   plot diver
   if ticks > 50 and ticks < 201 [set sumdiver sumdiver + diver]

   if ticks = 201 [
       set sumdiver sumdiver / 150
       output-type "mean = "
       output-type precision sumdiver 2
      ]  
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: puzzled what might be going on here. can you provide a URL for the complete .nlogo file? I don't understand how what you've shown so far could produce this error.

Comment: Thanks. A link to the full .nlogo file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7ft1exdc7v9yuh/diversity.nlogo?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This is a previously unreported bug in NetLogo. I'm glad you discovered it. I have minimized it and reported it here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/683

In order to work around it, you need to find a way to rewrite the code so it avoids using `stop` inside `foreach`.